# delay between between sending docs and actually seeing them in counter

Tags: elasticsearch

When I run:

```
http://bla:9200/_stats?pretty=true
```

I get (shortened):

```
_all" : {
    "primaries" : {
      "docs" : {
        "count" : 1005,
        "deleted" : 0
      },
      "store" : {
        "size_in_bytes" : 2348989104
      },
      "indexing" : {
        "index_total" : 1550,
```

The count is slower than the index_total and seem to lag. Is this because there is an actual delay between sending data and actually having them properly ingested/indexed? Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean with *slower* and *lag*. To me that sounds like after the *lag* is over the amounts are the same. Is this the case?

Comment: Yes. But is this to be expected?

Comment: How long is the lag approximately? Seconds, minutes, hours?

Comment: Do you have heavyweight ingest pipelines? And how does your sharding (amount of primaries and replicas) look like?

Comment: Bulk Ingest about 25 docs at the time using csharp